# What tool should I buy to cut through very hard plastic?

Tags: tools, plastic

I have this 55 gallon blue drum that I just picked up from car spa, but the top is not removable. What tool should I buy to remove just the top part of the plastic drum so that I can replace it with a wire mesh?

Update: I just looked into the Dremel tool, maybe this could work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dremel tool would work, but is very undersized for the job. It wll get HOT if you try it. A Rotozip or similar small router could do the job. If you're not too concerned about the look of the edge, a jigsaw with a course blade would work given a pilot hole to start with. Plastic does tend to vibrate and seize on jigsaws, so expect a rough ride.
Best choice is likely a small router with a rotozip style cutting-bit.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with your suggestion. Thanks for such helpful information.

Answer (score 5):

When we cut vinyl siding, my tool of choice is a circular saw with the blade installed backwards. By putting the blade in backwards, it will wear down the plastic with a smooth line rather than shred it with a rough edge. The thicker and harder the plastic, the slower you have to go.

If the circular saw doesn't work (perhaps because you can't make your cut as a straight line around the rim of the barrel) then a Sawzall is the quick way (I'd be tempted to use a blade with a high tooth count to reduce shredding). And if all you need is a small round hole, then your standard hole saw on a drill will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you just have one cut to make, you can probably use a hacksaw blade - something like [this](http://www.homedepot.ca/product/cg-mini-hack-utility-saw/925514) would probably work fine.

Answer (score 0):

TIL about a new (to me) tool for this kind of purpose (depending): a **hot knife**. It's basically a soldering iron but with a knife tip. **Very** cool.

Update: I got one and tried it out, this thing is awesome, super fun to use, and cuts through hard plastic like butter! The one I got is a Dominox DM-5H Hot Knife, that takes up to 190W and can adjust temperature up to 1kF (you could probably cut through plastic with just like 300, even, really though). The blade turns solid red, in like 15s, and it can even start a fire easily, right on the knife! Highly recommended (for competent adults, of course)!

P.S. Don't be fooled by the whole "foam cutter" thing. Sure, it can cut foam, but at these higher temperatures you can cut most materials!

[image: Dominox DM-5H Hot Knife]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).